# What medieval theologians debated whether angels are male or female?

Tags: catholicism, angels, sexuality, medieval-church, gender

Hildebrand, [*Man, Woman, and the Meaning of Love*](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8898), § "Friendship Between Man & Woman", §§ "There are many spiritual differences between the sexes" claims:

> In the Middle Ages the depth of this difference [between men and women] was totally understood, as evidenced by the interest in the question of whether the angels were also masculine and feminine.

What medieval theologians discussed this question? [St. Thomas's](https://isidore.co/aquinas/summa/FP.html#TOC03), [John of St. Thomas's](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7912), and [Súarez's](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7653) treatises on angels don't appear to discuss it.

I've [heard it claimed](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3gO0O7w5VBs) that our souls are male or female, yet St. Thomas denies this ([*Super Sent.*, lib. 4 d. 25 q. 2 a. 1 qc. 1 arg. 3](http://www.corpusthomisticum.org/snp4024.html#19092): "*Sed sexus non est in anima.* [But sex is not in the soul.]") and so does St. Ambrose ([*De Virginitate* cap. 15](https://archive.org/stream/patrologiaecur16mign#page/152/mode/2up): "*anima enim sexum non habet* [for the soul does not have a sex].").

Comment: In reply to the Sadducee's riddle on resurrection, Jesus says : " The people of this age marry and are given in marriage.  But those who are considered worthy of taking part in the age to come and in the resurrection from the dead will neither marry nor be given in marriage,  and they can no longer die; for they are like the angels ".Gen 5: 1-2 says: " When God created humankind, he made them in the likeness of God.   Male and female he created them..",So, if there is no marriage and procreation among angels, whey should they be he and she ?

Comment: "_if there is no marriage and procreation among angels, whey should they be he and she_" Yes, that's a good point; however, I'm wondering who Hildebrand was referring to.

Comment: Hildebrand appears to be referring to Francisco Suarez, SJ (1548-1617). In 1679 Pope Innocent XI publicly condemned sixty-five casuist propositions, taken chiefly from the writings of Escobar, Suárez and others, mostly Jesuit theologians as propositiones laxorum moralistarum and forbade anyone to teach them under penalty of excommunication (Courtesy: Wikipedia)

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan What's casuistry have to do with angelology?

Comment: Well, just to prove a point that Suarez is  one of the `blacklisted' theologians in so far as Catholic Church is concerned.

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan Suárez is an eclectic, sometimes Thomist, sometimes Scotist. Where does Suárez discuss the sex of angels?

Comment: In the review of Hildebrand, Man, Woman, and the Meaning of Love, § "Friendship Between Man & Woman" at ://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=8898, the writer (of the review) expresses his thought that Suarez ``might" have discussed the subject. (Courtesy: Your Question)

Comment: @KadalikattJosephSibichan I couldn't find any discussion on whether angels have a sex in Suárez's [_De angelis_](https://isidore.co/calibre/#panel=book_details&book_id=7653).